# How to send a message with NextPeer

Tags: api, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, nextpeer

I'm integrating NextPeer and the simple integration is done and works fine but now I need to send a custom message to the other player. 
In NextPeer documentation is explained like this:
To send data over an unreliable communication channel, use Nextpeer.UnreliablePushDataToOtherPlayers(byte[] data).
And this is what I'm trying to do:

Code (CSharp):

```
public void SendMessage(int intScore) {
      byte[ ] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes( intScore );
      Nextpeer.UnreliablePushDataToOtherPlayers(byte[] byteArray);
      // I tried printing it in cosole and works Debug.Log("To int " + BitConverter.ToInt16(byteArray, 0));
}
```

I'm getting this error in line where I'm calling Nextpeer.Unr...

```
Assets/scripts/nextpeer/NextpeerGameManager.cs(100,63): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `[', expecting `.'
```

What is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: shouldnt be Nextpeer.UnreliablePushDataToOtherPlayers(byteArray); , without the variables type?

Comment: @StackUnder Yes it was the problem. I figured it out after posting here/ thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Should be `Nextpeer.UnreliablePushDataToOtherPlayers(byteArray);`